# How to pass toolbar attributes to django-summernote SummernoteWidget?

Tags: django, wysiwyg, summernote

I am using django-summernote and I need to have custom toolbar on my form. I already customized SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG setting. But this particular form needs to have another settings. So I am using SummernoteWidget in form. Form is:

```
class CommentFormAuthenticated(forms.ModelForm):

    comment = forms.CharField(widget=SummernoteWidget(attrs={'width': '20%', 'height': '500px'}),)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['comment', ]
```

For example toolbar should have following settings:

```
'toolbar': [
            ['style', ['style']],
            ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'height']],
            ['insert', ['link']],
        ],
```

But this way in the doc they are used in settings.py as one of the parameters of SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG variable. So I am trying to implement these settings to SummernoteWidget in form like this:

```
class CommentFormAuthenticated(forms.ModelForm):

    comment = forms.CharField(widget=SummernoteWidget(attrs={
        'width': '20%', 
        'height': '500px',
        'toolbar': [
            ['style', ['style']],
            ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'height']],
            ['insert', ['link']],
        ]

    }),)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['comment', ]
```

But toolbar doesn't change at all. What is the right way to pass these settings to the SummernoteWidget?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do it in the `settings.py`

Something like this will work:

```
SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
    'iframe': True,
    'summernote': {
        # As an example, using Summernote Air-mode
        'airMode': False,
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '480',
        'toolbar': ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
    },
    'disable_attachment': True,
}
```

Comment: thanks bro I tried lot of js and jquey on client side

Answer (score 1):

This works:

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
```

Usage in forms:

```
## forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static
from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf.settings import SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG as summernote_config
from django_summernote.widgets import SummernoteWidget
from .models Post



class SummernoteWidgetWithCustomToolbar(SummernoteWidget):
    def summernote_settings(self):
        summernote_settings = summernote_config.get('summernote', {}).copy()
        lang = summernote_config['summernote'].get('lang')
        if not lang:
            lang = 'en-US'
        summernote_settings.update({
            'lang': lang,
            'url': {
                'language': static('summernote/lang/summernote-' + lang + '.min.js'),
                'upload_attachment': reverse('django_summernote-upload_attachment'),
                },
            'toolbar': [
                ['style', ['style', ]],
                ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'color', ]],
                ['paragraph', ['paragraph', 'ol', 'ul', ]],
                ['misc', ['link', 'undo', 'redo', 'help', ]],
                ],
        })
        return summernote_settings



class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields "__all__"
        widgets = {'body': SummernoteWidgetWithCustomToolbar()}
```

Usage in admin:

```
## admin.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static
from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf.settings import SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG as summernote_config
from django_summernote.widgets import SummernoteWidget
from .models import Post


class SummernoteModelAdminWithCustomToolbar(SummernoteWidget):
    def summernote_settings(self):
        summernote_settings = summernote_config.get('summernote', {}).copy()
        lang = summernote_config['summernote'].get('lang')
        if not lang:
            lang = 'en-US'
        summernote_settings.update({
            'lang': lang,
            'url': {
                'language': static('summernote/lang/summernote-' + lang + '.min.js'),
                'upload_attachment': reverse('django_summernote-upload_attachment'),
                },
            'toolbar': [
                ['style', ['style', ]],
                ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'color', ]],
                ['paragraph', ['paragraph', 'ol', 'ul', ]],
                ['misc', ['link', 'undo', 'redo', 'help', ]],
            ],
        })
        return summernote_settings


class CustomPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        widgets = {'body': SummernoteModelAdminWithCustomToolbar()}
        fields = "__all__"


class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CustomPostForm
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but according to the plugin docs, the toolbar configs are set in `settings.py`: https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote#options

That would be global, of course. I would suppose you could set them the conventional way (in javascript) as needed.

Comment: Well the docs also says: " Or, you can styling editor via attributes of the widget. These adhoc styling will override settings from SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG." It works, but not with toobalr attribute.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. My experience with plugins like this has been spotty at best. I've had better (and more well-documented) results just loading the .js library. Maybe give that a try?